# Extracting the hour from a time column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have the following dataset:

[image]

How would I create a new column, to be the hour of the time?

For example, the code below works for individual times, but I haven't been able to generalise it for a column in pandas.

```
t = datetime.strptime('9:33:07','%H:%M:%S')
print(t.hour)
```

Comment: you can use lambda functions: `df['col'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)`

Comment: This leads to the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hour'

Comment: That is because your time column is a str and not date time you will need to do `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` first

Comment: Ah of course, thanks Chris.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to datetimes with [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':['9:33:07','9:41:09']})

#should be slowier
#df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.hour

df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
print (df)
      TIME  hour
0  9:33:07     9
1  9:41:09     9
```

If want working with `datetime`s in column `TIME` is possible assign back:

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S')

df['hour'] = df['TIME'].dt.hour
print (df)
                 TIME  hour
0 1900-01-01 09:33:07     9
1 1900-01-01 09:41:09     9
```

Comment: To add, best to convert the entire series explicitly first, i.e. `df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])`. You will then also see memory benefits.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':['9:33:07','9:41:09']})
df['hour']= df.TIME.str.extract("(^\d+):", expand=False)
```

- "str.extract(...)" is a vectorized function that extract a regular expression pattern ( in our case "(^\d+):" which is the hour of the TIME) and return a Pandas Series object by specifying the parameter "expand= False"
- The result is stored in the "hour" column

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract() twice to feature out the 'hour' column

```
df['hour'] = df. TIME. str. extract("(\d+:)")
df['hour'] = df. hour. str. extract("(\d+)")
```