# How to group rows by hour of day in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with following data:

```
        kwh              time
0   0.217413    2019-04-09 17:00:00+00:00

1   4.133414    2019-04-09 18:00:00+00:00

2   5.154745    2019-04-09 19:00:00+00:00

3   2.497526    2019-04-09 20:00:00+00:00
```

The data represents kwh per hour. I am trying to group by hour of the day so that I can display:

```
  hour of day   sumkwh
    0             4
    1             5
    2             3
    23            6
```

I have tried a few options, but currently stuck.

```
s = df.groupby(df.time.hour).sum()

---> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

How could this be done?

Comment: cause you dont have a dataframe, you have a series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting the hour from a time column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045867/extracting-the-hour-from-a-time-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Try read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045867/extracting-the-hour-from-a-time-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

try this code it my help:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[0, 0.217413, "2019-04-09 17:00:00"], [1, 4.133414, "2019-04-09 18:00:00"], 
[2, 5.154745, "2019-04-09 19:00:00"], [3, 2.497526, "2019-04-09 20:00:00"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=["indx", "kwh", "hour"])
times = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.to_datetime(df["hour"]), columns=["hour"])
df.groupby(times.hour).sum()
```

Comment: Would it be possible to reference data = 0, column name1, 1, column name 2 etc as my data eventually will contain 100s/1000s of rows?